# NPE on Color.parseColor

Tags: android, android-resources

i'm getting a null pointer exception at the following code.

This is my resource file

```
<array name="category_colors">
    <item>#e57373</item>
    <item>#ef5350</item>
    <item>#f44336</item>
    <item>#e53935</item>
    <item>#d32f2f</item>
</array>
```

And this my function with the exception at "Color.parseColor"

```
private void insertCategories(String[] titles, String[] colors) {
    int i = 0;
    for (String title : titles) {
        final Category category = new Category();
        category.setTitle(title);
        category.setColor(Color.parseColor(colors[i % colors.length]));
        i++
        db.insert(Tables.Categories.TABLE, null, category.toContentValues());
    }
}
```

This is the calling method...

```
insertCategories(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories),
            context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_colors));
```

And my error :)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)'
```

I debugged the resource and they are available. In my other project the code works fine... Can anybody help me? Thx

Comment: Well.. i don't know why but wenn a copy the array from the colors.xml to the strings.xml my code works fine

Comment: That's strange. Glad it's working now.